# Executar duas ações em uma mesma Trigger no Postgres

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Estou tendo problemas com a trigger onde:

- A tabela `itens_compra_fornecedor` através da coluna `valor_compra` calcula o preço de revenda da coluna `valor_revenda`na tabela `produto` que não surte efeito.
- E também a outra ação da trigger é de atualizar o campo `data_relatorio_compra` da tabela `relatorio_compra_fornecedor`  que não retorna a data.

### Diagrama

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### A trigger de calcular o valor de revenda é essa

```
create or replace function preco_revenda()
    returns trigger as $$              
        begin                   
        new.valor_revenda := (select sum (itens_compra_fornecedor.valor_compra + (itens_compra_fornecedor.valor_compra * 0.5)) 
        from produto where produto.cd_itens_compra_fornecedor = new.cd_itens_compra_fornecedor);

        update relatorio_compra_fornecedor set data_compra_fornecedor = now()                         
        from relatorio_compra_fornecedor where relatorio_compra_fornecedor.cd_relatorio_compra_fornecedor = new.cd_relatorio_compra_fornecedor;
        
        return new;
        end                    
            $$ language plpgsql;

create trigger preco_revenda
before insert or update on produto              
for each row                       
execute procedure preco_revenda();
```

Comment: Se quiserem que eu atualize a figura pra mostrar o banco todo me avisem, só que eu posso pedir ajuda para outras trigger caso precise, me ajudando em disparar esse relatório posso usar o código para também disparar outras triggers de relatório de venda do produto e relatório devolução.

Comment: Por favor só não fechem minha pergunta, porque realmente eu preciso de ajuda em fazer o meu sistema web para a matéria da faculdade.

Comment: Não dá para fazer as duas ações no mesmo gatilho? Existe algum outro motivo para que sejam dois gatilhos?

Comment: @anonimo eu pensei que dava pra executar duas ações no mesmo gatilho.

Comment: Então coloque em seu gatilho um update da tabela relatorio_compra_fornecedor.

Comment: @anonimo ```update relatorio_compra_fornecedor set data_compra_fornecedor = now() from relatorio_compra_fornecedor where relatorio_compra_fornecedor.cd_relatorio_compra_fornecedor = new.cd_relatorio_compra_fornecedor;```?